# DropDown menu shows items twicely using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-hosted-app

i want to load items to drop down list dynamically from list where items are stored in SharePoint hosted app,I am done with this functionality [by referring this article](https://sharepointkitchen.blogspot.in/2014/12/create-sharepoint-hosted-app.html?showComment=1471495416391#c4351262877987473063) but having a small issue that the items got added and displayed twicely in that drop down list

dropdown control

```
<select id="ddl2">

</select>
```

my java script code is as below

```
function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {
    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
    var strParams = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)
            return decodeURIComponent(singleParam[1]);
    }
}
spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
SPAppWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

$(document).ready(function () {
    getItems_List();
});

function getItems_List() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(SPAppWebUrl);//Get the SharePoint Context object based upon the URL
    var myList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("TestList");
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var items = myList.getItems(query);

    // ctx.load(myList);
    ctx.load(items);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        PopulateValues(items, "#ddl2", "Title");

    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
function PopulateValues(listItems, ddl, columnName) {
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

    var ddlList = $(ddl);
    if (listEnumerator.$2K_0 > 0) {
        ddlList.append("<option>Location</option>");
    }
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        var optionValue = "<option value='" + listItem.get_item(columnName) + "'>" +
            listItem.get_item(columnName) + "</option>";
        ddlList.append(optionValue);
    }
}
```

output of above code is as bellow
[image]

expected output is
[image]

can any one help?

Comment: To troubleshoot: Check getItems_List1() method is not called twice or PopulateValues11 is not called twice . You are using append, so if this is called twice , it will append to the already created options. And I see mismatch in method names "PopulateValues" and "PopulateValues11"

Comment: sorry that was a silly mistake,while posting code

Comment: i have updated my code posted entire code here

Comment: try using debugger in the browser and see how many times call is made to PopulateValues

Comment: Clear your dropdown, before appending. at this line var ddlList = $(ddl);